# Unexpected token ':' on an node api service when making a function strongly typed

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, es6-modules

I have a node api service written in typescript, below is my sample code

```
class dataStreamConfig {
    constructor() { }

    conclaveObj = (firstParam: string, secondParam: number, thirdParam: any): any => {
        //my business logic goes here
       //return Obj

    };
}

module.exports = dataStreamConfig ;
```

Im getting the below error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
```

If i remove the types (string, number, any) from the function, then it is working fine. 
I have tried to redo npm install.

Also i did npm install babel-cli babel-preset-es2015.

**Update**

Below is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "sourceMap": true
    }
  }
```

Also i have typescript installed globally. I compile the project using tsc command at the root, also i have tried running tsc on the directory which has the class.

Would really appreciate any help / suggestion in this issue.

Comment: Try removing `: any` which is present before `=>`.

Comment: Your code just containing syntax error

Comment: @KaustubhKhare , tried, it gave the same error but this time highlighting on the thirdParam, i get the below error
thirdParam: any) => {
                        ^

Comment: Did you compile Typescript code?

Comment: @Vishal-Lia yes i have compiled my code.

Comment: Can you share how you compiled and also the "tsconfig.json". Check https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html if it helps

Comment: @Vishal-Lia i have updated the question with tsconfig code and how i compile the solution.

Comment: Is this error a warning from your IDE or a runtime error?

Answer (score 0):

try getting rid of the arrow function and using the normal way of writing a function with the function keyword .. Do note the last any in this function denotes the type this function will return and this is optional. typescript can also detect this itself. so it doesn't matter if you provide it or not...

```
class dataStreamConfig {
constructor() { }

   let conclaveObj = function (firstParam: string, secondParam: number, thirdParam: any): any {
    //my business logic goes here
   //return Obj

};
```

`}`

```
module.exports = dataStreamConfig ;
```

for more help you can visit thier documentation ...
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Comment: Shafeeq, tried the code without arrow function, but it still gives me the same exception.